# Regarding about file input and output in C

Tags: c, file, input, output

I normally don't ask questions on here unless I'm really stuck! I was wondering if anyone can please explain why my code prints out a '5 47'. I understand why there is a 5, but not why there is a 47? I looked up the ASCII values for blankspace (32) and I tried changing the second letter to e, f, g, for example but the output remains '5 47' unchanged.

In general, when I use `fscanf(fp, "%d", &variablename)`, does the `fscanf` skip over miscellaneous characters? For example: in my file test.txt I had "`5 hello 6 ben jerry\n`". How would I scan in the 5 and the 6? Would `fscanf(fp, "%d %d", &test1, &test2)` scan in the 5 and 6, skipping over the word "hello"?

Here is my simple code I am using to test output:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int blah, test;
  FILE * fp;
  fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
  fscanf(fp, "%d %d", &blah, &test);
  printf("%d %d\n", blah, test);
  return 0;
}
```

My file I am using as argv[1] contents:

```
5g
```

P.S. is `FILE *fp` an actual pointer to each character/number and does it work as a placeholder when it scans through the file? Is that why we need `rewind(fp)` once it hits the end of the file?

Comment: You never checked the result of that `fscanf`, which would have told you only one value was successfully parsed. As you never initialized `test`, its value is indeterminate, and so shall your output be. How `fscanf()` behaves can be read about [**here**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) or go straight to the source and read the C standards.

Comment: I'm confused. So does the fscanf scan in the g or a blankspace into test or not? It works fine for 'blah'... Why wouldnt  it work for 'test'? I looked at that page & I still don't understand why. Please elaborate. Thanks

Comment: I cannot describe it better than the authors of cppreference (which are *very* well-spoken members of the C/C++ community). That link is a Rossetta Stone for how the `scanf` family of functions work, and worth more than a mere 5 minutes of your time.

Answer (score 1):

The operator %d looks for an integer, not a character. Because g is a character, not an integer, %d is getting confused and the output will not always be 5 47. The 47 could be anything. it could be 5 7, 5 23 etc. This is because the fscanf is not reading a second number, so no value is being assigned to test. Therefore, test remains at the value which was sitting in that piece of memory when the program was initiated.

To fix this, replace %d with %c and change the type of blah and test to int. Also, as WhozCraig said, it is good practise to check the return value of fscanf to check that two values have been found. This way, you can be sure that everything you're looking for has been found.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the `scanf()` family of functions stop reading when they come across a character that is not expected by the format string.  The unexpected character is left in the input for the next input operation to process.

If you want to read two integers that are definitely separated by a 'word' that is not an integer, then you will need to skip the word.  If you don't know in advance what the word will be, you need to use assignment suppression (see the POSIX [`scanf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/scanf.html) page for lots of information).

Hence, your code to read the two integers from input containing

```
5 hello 6 ben jerry
```

should be:

```
if (fscanf(fp, "%d %*s %d", &blah, &test) != 2)
    …Oops; format error?…
```

Note that the code tests that it got the expected result.  However, if you don't know whether there'll be a word between the two numbers, you are much better off using `fgets()` and `sscanf()` because you can try different parses of the same line:

```
char buffer[4096];

while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), fp) != 0)
{
    if (sscanf(buffer, "%d %*s %d", &blah, &test) == 2)
        …got two numbers with a word — let's go!
    else if (sscanf(buffer, "%d %d", &blah, &test) == 2)
        …got two numbers but no word — let's go!
    else
        …didn't recognize the format…
}
```

One of the major advantages of this is that you can report the error in terms of the complete line of input, rather than just the part that `fscanf()` didn't manage to work on.

Your last question, about a `FILE *`, is not a pointer to each character in the file.  It is a handle which allows you to invoke functions that take a file pointer argument to read from or write to the associated file. However, you can't use indexing based on the file pointer (so `fp[1024]` does *not* identify the character at offset 1024 in the file or anything useful like that).  If you want that sort of behaviour, you need a memory-mapped file ([`mmap()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/mmap.html) for POSIX systems).